# When can I drop absolute value bars for ODE's

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$dx/dt = -x/t$

$ \int 1/x \,dx = \int -1/t \,dt $

$ln|x| = -ln|t|+c$

$e^{-ln|t|+c} = |x|$

$Ae^{-ln|t|} = |x|$

At this next step, can I just drop the absolute value bars because we can absorb that into $A$? If so, then we have

$A'e^{-ln|t|} = x$

$x = A'/e^{ln|t|} $

At this point, can I drop the absolute value bars for $t$ as well? to get $x = A'/t$?

I'm confused when to drop these absolute bars and why I can. I'm even more confused for $x' = x/2t$

Comment: Generally, initial value problems are solved for $t>0$, given initial data $x(0)$. In that case $|t|=t$.

Comment: Is the $A$ the same constant for $x>0$ and for $x<0$? You have to be very, very careful when the domain has a hole (or holes) in it.

Comment: When you are solving differential equations, you assume everything is differentiable on some interval, so $|x|$ can be only identically equal to $x$ or $-x$ in most cases. That can be absorbed to constant anytime.

Comment: @Esgeriath Be careful. You can have different constants on the different connected components of the domain.

Comment: @TedShifrin well, I only solve ODE's in one component at a time (as I wrote, on some interval). If domain wasn't connected then you could have very different functions on different components

Comment: @Esgeriath 40 years of teaching have taught me that students don't pay attention to such details. I just wanted to emphasize it here.